# How can I exit java for-loop if user enters 999?

Tags: java, for-loop, exit, break

I need to write a program that allows a student to enter up to 10 quiz scores, computes the average score, and then displays the letter grade based on the average. However, if the user enters 999 during the input of quiz scores, the program will terminate. This is the code block I wanted to insert a break statement into but I'm struggling to correctly incorporate grade[i] = 999 into my code without getting an error message. I think the issue may be that the 999 is an integer array value and is unrelated to the int i counter in the for loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   //prompts user to enter grade + displays counter value
   System.out.print("Enter grade " + (i + 1) + " or enter 999 to quit: ");
   //allows user input to be stored in variable grade
   grade[i] = scanner.nextInt();
   //adds new grade input to total grade to update variable gradeTotal
   gradeTotal = gradeTotal + grade[i];
```

Comment: After the prompt `("Enter grade ...`, accept the input into a temporary `int`. If the temporary `== 999` `break`. If not, copy it to `grade[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the inputted value to a temporary variable, and then if it is 999 break the loop, else assign it the the array.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.print("Enter grade " + (i + 1) + " or enter 999 to quit: ");
   int temp = scanner.nextInt();
   if (temp == 999) {
      break;
   }
   grade[i] = temp;
   ...
```